# Tooltip returning [object, Object]

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, scatter-plot

I am attempting to complete the scatter plot [exercise](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/ONxvaa) from free code camp. However, I have only been learning d3 on my own for a few hours now and I am stuck trying to determine how to display specific data in the tooltip after following a tutorial from lynda.com.[This](https://codepen.io/nlpro/pen/BWJJvG) codepen is what I have so far.

I create the tooltip by doing the following:

```
 var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
.style('position', 'absolute')
.style('padding', '0 10px')
.style('background', 'white')
.style('opacity', 0)
```

Then I do the following to show the tooltip

```
.on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
tooltip.transition()
  .style('opacity', .9)
tooltip.html(d)
  .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
  .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px')
})

  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .style('opacity', 1)
  })

  myChart.transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return i * 20;
    })
    .duration(1000)
    .ease('elastic')
```

When I replace `tooltip.html(d)` with

```
tooltip.html(function(d, i){
    return d[i].Name; 
})
```

Nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put `console.log(d)` in function. What will you see in console? Maybe you should return `d.Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3, the first parameter, normally named `d`, is the *datum*. Right now, your datum is an object like this:

```
{
    "Time": "38:36",
    "Place": 11,
    "Seconds": 2316,
    "Name": "Floyd Landis",
    "Year": 2006,
    "Nationality": "USA",
    "Doping": "Stripped of 2006 Tour de France title",
    "URL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd_Landis_doping_case"
}
```

Thus, you have to access their values by their keys:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
    tooltip.transition()
        .style('opacity', .9)
    tooltip.html("Name: " + d.Name + "<br>Year: " + d.Year + "<br>Dopping: " + d.Doping)
        .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
        .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px')
})
```

Here is your updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpdyZv